# Clickable list view

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to create clickable listView.
The listView is Working good but clickable listView not.
When I clicked on one of the listView elements it's not responding.

Here is my code:

```
public class ResturantListFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<Resturant> res = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView resturantList ;
    private ListAdapter adapter;


    public ResturantListFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

        resturantList = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listtt);


        String[] names = {"Soho","Rustico","Mac","Yoni","Ofir","Or","mio","north","ao,","fgfg"};
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++){
            res.add(new Resturant(i,names[i]));
        }
        adapter = new ListAdapter(getContext(),res);
        resturantList.setAdapter(adapter);

        resturantList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                Log.d("press on:","12234234234234");
            }

        });
```

Comment: post code of ListAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        Product[] items = {
            new Product(1, "Milk", 21.50),
            new Product(2, "Butter", 15.99),
            new Product(3, "Yogurt", 14.90),
            new Product(4, "Toothpaste", 7.99),
            new Product(5, "Ice Cream", 10.00),
        };

        ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);

        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {

                String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

for more see [Example 1](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/handling-android-listview-onitemclick-event) [Example 2](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html)